Problema al renderizar una determinada webview en una actividad nativa de android
Estoy teniendo problemas para renderizar una determinada web en mi actividad nativa android. El problema en si, no es con todas las webs, ya que si renderizo webs como Amazon, Facebook, Disney +, etc. me funcionan a la perfección, pero con la web que me interesa no funciona, me queda la pantalla en "blanco".
Al principio pensaba que podría tratarse de un tema de certificados, pero aparentemente no es un problema de seguridad:

El código java de mi actividad es:
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class OutgoingCallActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       getSupportActionBar().hide();

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_outgoing_call);

       Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
       webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
       webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           @Override
           public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, 
             WebResourceError error) {
               Log.e("WEBVIEW_ERROR", error.toString());
           }

           @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               super.onPageFinished(view, url);
               Log.d("WEBVIEW", "onPageFinished: " + url);
               view.evaluateJavascript(
               "(function() { return document.body.innerHTML; })();",
                    new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                            Log.d("HTML", html);
                        }
                    });
            }
       });
       webView.loadUrl("https://www.amazon.com/");
       webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String number = "123456";
               Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
               Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, call);
               startActivity(surf);
               Log.d("OutgoingCallActivity", "Button Pressed");
           }
       });
   }
}

class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
       mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sendMessageToApp(String deeplink) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(deeplink));
       mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

La actividad consiste en una webview y un botón nativo:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".OutgoingCallActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#5bc500"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="Resume Call" />
</LinearLayout>

No estoy seguro si me falta agregar alguna configuración extra en mi código nativo o si bien tengo que agregar o corregir algo en la web.
Este comportamiento me ocurre en todas las versiones de android con las que he probado, desde la 7.1.1 hasta la 13, tanto en emulador de android como en dispositivos reales.
Como mencionaba anteriormente, cuando intento renderizar la url de la web que estoy interesado en cargar, lo que sucede es que queda en "blanco":

Pero si intento cargar webs como amazon, disney +, facebook, etc. no tengo ningún problema, se renderizan a la perfección:

En el código agrego logs para verificar si ocurre algún error al intentar renderizar una url, pero en el logcat de Android Studio me muestra como que la página se cargó correctamente, es decir, nunca se me ejecuta el evento onReceivedError que acuse que se esté originando un error.
Probé varias cosas, pero aún no doy con el problema. Espero que alguno de ustedes tenga una idea de cuál prodría ser el problema.
